# Can I set max width in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a layout with some media queries and it works and looks ok apart from on an ipad in portrait mode where it will have a horizontal scrollbar and lots of blank space at the side. I have a container and I've tried 100% and 750px width but its still there.

Is there anyway I can specify the max width of the page and anything outside that would be discarded?

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: Place width on your container and `overflow : hidden` ?

Comment: Your 'solution' to the Ipad issue should be to fix your code not hide stuff because it's inconvenient.

Comment: So I went through it and found that the error is caused by 

      <script src="js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
        
Why would this add padding to my page?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your css:

```
 max-width:750px;
 width:100%;
```